# How to increment Django CharField (containing an integer) using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, char, django-orm, increment

Say I have a model as :

```
class model(models.Model):
    remark=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    count=models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

The entity having remark="counter" has count="34". I wish to retrieve entity (having remark="counter") and change its count to "35", i.e. cast to integer, increment it by 1, cast back to string, update.

Is there any way I can do this using only Django ORM query(using F or something else) and no Python.

Comment: Please do *not* use a `CharField` to store numeric data...

Comment: Seeing the entire database design, it needs to be. Is there a Django ORM query to implement above updation ?

Comment: so say `count` contain` count='blabla'`, then how would that work. Using a `CharField` is not only inefficient in space and time, it is horrible design that allows all sorts of problems. For example in a `CharField`, `"001"` and `"1"` are different, but in an `IntegerField`, the two are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really need to do this, despite all the red flags, F() functions should do the trick.  Most databases implicitly convert strings and ints as required, so you can just do this:

```py
Model.objects.filter(...).update(count=F('count')+1)
```

Comment: The ORM itself will give you an error here unless you specify what the output should be. See this section [Using F() with annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations). You need to use an `ExpressionWrapper` and specify the `output_field`. In fact you should best use the [`Cast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function rather than thinking of conversion happening implicitly.

Comment: I've tested this on django 3.2, and it worked just fine without output_field

Comment: That is not possible unless your `count` field was some type of numeric field. This is as evidenced from the source code in GitHub itself. See [`_resolve_output_field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e4430f22c8e3d29ce5d9d0263fba57121938d06d/django/db/models/expressions.py#L284-L309) of `BaseExpression`, [`_resolve_output_field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e4430f22c8e3d29ce5d9d0263fba57121938d06d/django/db/models/expressions.py#L465-L476) of `CombinedExpression`. There is a bit more code you can explore yourself, but simply put this will raise an error.

Comment: Nope, I'm running it on an nvarchar field.  I've just run it repeatedly without error.  Outputs the expected SQL, updates the object fine.  Put a non-numeric value in the field, and it errors, as we all expect.

Comment: _resolve_output_field doesn't appear to be called when using a CombinedExpression in a bare fashion like this, directly used as an update value.  As soon as you combine it with other ORM functions (e.g. Cast, .annotate...), output_field becomes required.